# Minimum weight triangulation

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, recursion

I'm just curious about the pseudocode (or real source code, doesn't matter) of the recursive version of this algorithm. In almost every book chapter/paper when describing this topic, they mention that the recursive version takes exponential time and then they give the code for the dynamic programming approach. I understand how the iterative version (dynamic programming ie. memoization) works. But i just wonder about the recursive version.
For the info, the key part in the iterative code is:

> $\ell$ ... left 
>   $r$ ... right 
>   $a$ ... apex 
>   $T$ ... triangulation
>
> $T_{\ell,r}= \min\{T_{\ell,a} + \text{perimeter}_{\ell,a,r} + T_{a,r}\}$

So how does the recursive function `findOT()` seem in 
pseudocode or one of these languages (C#, Java, C/C++, PHP, Javascript, SML)?

Comment: I suppose you talk about triangulating a polygon. Please Clarify. You should also be precise about what makes it difficult for your to turn the recursion into source code. Also, **what recursion**?

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433989/recursive-version-of-minimum-weight-triangulation

Comment: @Schulz yes. the triangulation of a convex polygon.
i just need the source code for the recursive version of this algorithm.

Comment: @Realz i know. i posted the same question also in stackoverflow to increase the chance that the question is replied.

Comment: @HasanTahsin: Please don't crosspost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to say, what kind recursion you mean. There are different variants I can think of. For what you have written, I guess it is something like this.

```
function findOT(int l,r)

if ((r-l)==2) return perimeter(l,l+1,r)

min= infinity
for a=(l+1)..(r-1)
    T=findOT(l,a)+perimeter(l,a,r)+findOT(a,r) 
    if T<min then min=T
    endfor
return(min)
```

Comment: thx for the answer. is there also a plain recursive way without using a for loop?

Comment: @HasanTahsin: You can formulate every loop as recursion, but what's the point in doing this. This is going to be very artificial code. The pseudo-code above is usually understood as recursive solution.